# Adding src attribute to <script>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
script_url = 'http://externaldomain.com/script.js'
div_id = 'div'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
document.write('<div id="'+div_id+'"><scr'+'ipt id="banner-to-load"></scr'+'ipt></div>')
```

After DOM is ready i do this:

```
$('#banner-to-load').attr('src',script_url)
```

Now, `script_url` appended, but nothing happens. External script has some functions and `document.write`, but they don't work. How can i run external script? Or if i run it `document.write` inside will rebuild my already compiled DOM?

Comment: *Or if i run it `document.write` inside will rebuild my already compiled DOM?* Yes.

Comment: Have you tried `$('#banner-to-load').prop('src',script_url);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting src before you add it and recheck your script_url.

```
document.write('<div id="'+div_id+'"><script '
  +'id="banner-to-load" src="' + script_url + '"></scr'+'ipt></div>')
```

**Update**: Or make a cross domain Ajax Query. If you control the other page you can allow cross domain queries by setting the "[Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin)" header.

Comment: You can also use the Yahoo proxy for cross domain queries: http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Answer (score 2):

The src attribute is not loaded asynchronously. Load your js with ajax

```
$.getScript(); or $.ajax({url:source, dataType: "script"});
```

Have a look here 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: Yes, that's a common issue.Make a PHP script to use as a cross domain scripting proxy and load it via ajax

Comment: Cross domain is no problem. I do it all the time. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to append the `banner_to_load` to the body object